# ESP8266 Web Server Crash + Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, web-server, http

I am working on HTTP GET Request. I have created ESP wifi as web server. It creates a access point with IP address : 192.168.4.1 
When my android app is connected to web server, it sends values every 50ms on 192.168.4.1/R"VALUE". Value is integer type (0~1023). Example :- 192.168.4.1/R546

However, it is working fine when I send values every 1s, but esp crashes, when IP is hit every 5ms second. I have captured the crash detail on serial monitor. Attaching the file and code as well. Kindly help. [image]

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define RED_LED     12

WiFiServer server(80); //Initialize the server on Port 80

char myTestUrl[100];

void setup()
{

  EEPROM.begin(512);
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start communication between the ESP8266-12E and the monitor window

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP); //Our ESP8266-12E is an AccessPoint
  WiFi.softAP("LED_Downlight1", "12345678"); // Provide the (SSID, password); .
  server.begin(); // Start the HTTP Server

  IPAddress HTTPS_ServerIP = WiFi.softAPIP(); // Obtain the IP of the Server
  Serial.print("Server IP is: "); // Print the IP to the monitor window
  Serial.println(HTTPS_ServerIP);
}


void loop()
{
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client)
  {
    return;
  }

  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  //Serial.print(request);

  request.toCharArray(myTestUrl, 100);

  char *Red = strstr(myTestUrl, "/R");
  if (Red)
  {
    int RedValue  = atoi(Red + 2);
    analogWrite(RED_LED, RedValue);
    Serial.print("Red: ");
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(RedValue);
    Serial.print("\n");

    int SetRedValue = (RedValue / 4);
    EEPROM.write(0, SetRedValue);

    EEPROM.commit();

    Serial.print("Red Memory Write :");
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(SetRedValue);
    Serial.print("\n \n");

  }
}
```

Comment: Exception(29) = A store referenced a page mapped with an attribute that does not permit stores - information from [this page](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/exception_causes.md) - personally I wouldn't be using EEPROM like that

Comment: So what is the best way to use EEPROM? How can I improve my code? Any Suggestion or sketch would be useful.

Comment: One reason you may get the error is that writing to EEPROM is exceptionally slow (compared to other memory operations) and I wouldn't use EEPROM to store data like that for two reasons. 1) you never read it, so why store it. 2) EEPROM has limited write cycles, write many times a second, you will reach (permanent) failure point sooner rather than later

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with ESP8266 to create a centralized network over which different devices could communicate. In my first iteration I used an ESP8266 as an AP and let other ESP8266s connect to it. This didn't work for longer than 5 minutes. I suspected the ESP8266 couldn't handle many connections for a long period of time and bought an USB WiFi router. Now, I connected all ESP8266 to the WiFi router, including the ESP8266 that I set up as server. And it worked.

In other words: the ESP8266 isn't *strong* enough to be an AP and communicate a lot of data at the same time. Instead, you'd rather like your ESP connect to an existing wireless network with other devices and let those devices connect to the IP of the ESP.